# Problem installing tabletop_object_perception package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to use the tabletop_object_perception package
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tabletop_object_perception

The binary for ros-electric-tabletop_object_perception downloads only 3 files and so, i attempted installing from the SVN source of it.

There were lot of dependencies unresolved and i have been installing many of those from the SVN sources. There are compilation errors in many trunks , like motion_planning_common and also tabletop_object_detector .

```
"/ros_electric/tabletop_object_perception/tabletop_object_detector/include/tabletop_object_detector/marker_generator.h:45:41: error: geometric_shapes_msgs/Shape.h: No such file or directory"
```

Has anyone managed to get the entire package working ? is there a binary for the package with all the dependencies available ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12175/problem-installing-tabletop_object_perception-package/) by [enschulfer schmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1452/enschulfer-schmidt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2012-02-12**:
I have exactly the same problem. Maybe somebody has found a solution in the meantime and could share it?

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2012-04-03**:
No one? There seems to be discrepancy between tabletop_object_detector and electric. geometric_shapes_msgs was part of motion_planning_common, which became arm_navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tabletop_object_perception no longer exists in Electric except as an empty stack. tabletop_object_detector is now in the stack pr2_object_manipulation, which you can get in debs as ros-electric-pr2-object-manipulation , or from Electric-trunk at

https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_object_manipulation/branches/0.5-branch

I apologize if you were using the address on the wiki; it's terribly confusing, but the wiki is still giving Diamondback svn addresses, which do not compile against Electric debs.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-08-15**:
But, I cannot see any ..tabletop_object... package in the [pr2_object_manipulation](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_object_manipulation) stack. In contrast, tabletop_object_perception is linked from that stack. In either case, *please* add a deprecation/moved note where it suits.

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2012-08-15**:
Good point.  I added notes to both wiki pages, along with the urls for Electric and Fuerte code.